# clickAndHold is not working in Selenium webdriver (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a function with actions like click, focus, etc. and works fine, but I need the function clickAndHold and returns an error when I try to run test.

This is a piece of code of my function:

```
def start_action(self, selector, action, value):
browser = self.d
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(selector)
if action == 'clickAndHold':
        actions = ActionChains(browser)
        actions.clickAndHold(element)
        actions.perform()
```

And this is the error:

```
AttributeError: 'ActionChains' object has no attribute 'clickAndHold'
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python this method called [`click_and_hold()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.click_and_hold). Try to use it instead of `clickAndHold()`

Note that in Python in most cases *snake_case* used instead of *camelCase*